# How to ignore SSL Certificate Name Mismatch in Python (xmlrpc)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

Whilst trying to communicate with a server by using Python's XML-RPC library:

```
import xmlrpc.client
url = 'https://12345/'

api = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(url)
print(api.system.listMethods())
```

I am getting this error:

```
ssl.py  in match_hostname ssl.CertificateError: hostname '12345' doesn't match '*.hostname.com'
```

Obviously, I can alter the source of ssl.py to ignore this, but is there a better way like a parameter I can set etc?

Comment: Ignoring a non-matching hostname is nearly as bad as doing no certificate validation at all. An attacker can now do a man-in-the-middle attack with any certificate signed by a public CA, no matter which hostname the certificate is for. Such a certificate is trivially to get. You should instead aim to check against the hostname you expect in the certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich +1. OTOH you can communicate over HTTP to ignore this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such setting in `xmlrpc` library for obvious reasons. Thus the only way to accomplish this is to remove validation from ssl.py.

Note: I was writing a real world system that would communicate with an external provider via HTTPS. But before we were able to put it live we had to test with their dev-server, which had different hostname hence the certificate error. So there was no security risk as only dev-server credentials were used and some dummy data.

Answer (score 3):

A current version of python has an additional context parameter that can use a custom SSL context:

```
import xmlrpc.client
import ssl
url = 'https://12345/'

api = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(url,context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
print(api.system.listMethods())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).